# Running a packaged exe in the same folder as the installed firefox add-on

Tags: firefox-addon, executable, launching-application

I have read this thread, and some other
[How to run a local exe in my firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490713/how-to-run-a-local-exe-in-my-firefox-extension)

The problem is, at deployment and using firefox 4.0.1, if I install the .xpi extension, the xpi is put inside the \Profiles...\extensions as ****.xpi, which is a compressed format

All the solutions assume that the the extension is put in a folder, thus they are accessing the folder as is, which I cannot do

for example this guy says

```
//**** get profile folder path ****
  var dsprops = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1']
      .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties);
  var ProfilePath = dsprops.get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path;

//**** initialize file ****
  var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
      .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
  file.initWithPath(ProfilePath);

//**** append each step in the path ****
  file.append("extensions");
  file.append("guid");
  file.append("sample.exe");
```

guid in my case is installed as {f13b157f-b174-47e7-a34d-4815ddfdfeb8}.xpi which cannot be accessible this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please do not locate files like this - you are making lots of assumptions about the directory structure of the Firefox profile, any of those could turn out false in a future Firefox version (or even in uncommon extension setup scenarios). See [Reference a binary-component to js-ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175608/reference-a-binary-component-to-js-ctypes-firefox-addon/6257595#6257595) instead for code to locate a file in your extension install directory, simply replace `components/linux/myLib.so` by `sample.exe` and execute `uri.file`.

Second: that's a scenario where packed XPI installation won't work unless you want to extract your executable into a temporary file before running it (which will be complicated). Windows doesn't support running executables from ZIP archives. So you need to add `<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>` to your extension's install.rdf to ensure that it is installed as an unpacked directory.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is to get flashgot Firefox addon , which contanins already executable inside , and is open source , and , study it , this is great way to observe how this actually works. Based on this , You can make as much as You wish addons with executable inside , or add entire program as FF addon. I hope this helps , even if this answer is rather than outdated.