# How to run this ActiveX based javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, activex, activexobject

I am trying to run the below code which launches notepad. IE tab is nice solution, but loading is slow. I gave the try to ff-activex-host.I downloaded the binary exe. I copied the npffax.dll to firefox plugin folder(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\plugins) . But, still
the above code is not working. I am getting the message "ActiveXObject is not defined" in web console. Can anybody shed a light on this issue?.  Please clear me of running this code. This is the code I am trying.

```
var commandtoRun ="C:\\WINDOWS\\notepad.exe";
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
oShell.run(commandtoRun);
```

**EDIT:**
    Any suggestion to run the above code in firefox is welcomed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490713/how-to-run-a-local-exe-in-my-firefox-extension

Comment: `npffax.dll` is outdated and unsupported, you shouldn't use it. You should write a proper extension if you need advanced functionality.

Comment: @Wladimir Any link or sample code can make a great help to me.

Comment: @prabhakaran: You already have the sample code in the answer below. Other than that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772/how-do-i-write-a-firefox-addon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Running_applications):

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]  
                 .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);  
file.initWithPath("c:\\myapp.exe");  
file.launch();
```

Keep in mind, this is not cross-browser and will not work on Linux. If this is critical for you, - use `nsIProcess` interface, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess

Comment: Is it possible to pass command line arguments in this?. If it is so can you say how to do that?.

Comment: yes, will need to use `nsIProcess`. See example, near the bottom of the linked page, it shows, how to pass args.

Comment: Doesn't work with the latest versions of firefox, the components object is getting deleted

Comment: intersting... @NathanvanderWerf do you have a proof link ? with rationale and workaround (if any) ?

Comment: Didn't find any workaround, but try this code in firefox and you'll get the error in firebug console from firefox :)